# Finding table name in encrypted SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I would like to find a table refence in SSIS package but if I check directly the package file, it is encrypted so I guess this is not possible, isn't it?
I tried to find it also on SQL Server agent db but there in table : [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages] but there isn't xml information so it is the wrong table I am checking ?
SQL server 2019

Comment: Why?...What's your main goal?

Comment: Save time to search for a table in which package it is

Comment: Why do you want to find this table though?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this question is related to possible solution really.
But I need it in order to find out what a specific table is used for , what data is coming in etc.

Comment: And you don't have access to the source decompiled SSIS package's project?

Comment: Yes, I have access in ssis to the projects but I have many projects and would like to find more effective way to find in which project and control flow task a table is used instead  of going though all projects manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132090/discussion-between-j-d-and-gk1993-aal).